# PuTTY Cntrl Characters

Tags: ascii, putty

Using PuTTY to talk with my PIC chip over a Serial connection.  I want to recognize `<CR> <Backspace> <Cursor Up> <Cursor Dwn> <Cursor left> <Cursor Right>` and do the correct thing in the LCD display.

I figured this should be easy enough.  Just go look at an Ascii table and use the Hex values being sent.  Problem is I guess PuTTY sends more than one value for each of the cntrl char values.

Is there a list I can refer to for these values that I can modify my code with or is the answer starring me in the face?

Comment: Cursor down and cursor up are _definitely_ going to be funny, as those aren't standard ASCII characters but are terminal-dependent sequences of characters. CR, LF, BS, DEL, should all be one byte though... Is there a specific terminal emulation you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of PuTTY's protocols, but ASCII does define escape characters - Control+key. To be more specific, ASCII 0 is Control-@, 1 through 26 (0x1 through 0x1a) are Control+the corresponding letter of the alphabet.